# Fastest way to iterate over two panda data frames

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have two data frames:

`dt1` where I store millions of registry key entries. Defined with columns: `Index([u'count', u'id', u'is_malicious', u'key', u'name', u'value'], dtype='object')`

And `dt2` where I match those registry entries to machines across our network. Defined with columns: `Index([u'id', u'machine_id', 'registry_key_id'], dtype='object')`

**What is the fastest way to iterate over all the rows in `dt1`, and for each row, count how many times `row['id']` is found in `dt2` column `row['registry_key_id']`?**

The pseudocode can be thought as:

```
for row in dt1:
  row['count'] = count(dt2[dt2['registry_key_id'] == row['id']]
```

Right now we are using `for index, row in panda.iterrows():` but it's quite slow when it comes to processing hundreds of thousands of rows. We are looking for method to considerably accelerate that process.

Thank you for your assistance.

**Update 1:**

See the code below:

```
count = count.groupby('registry_key_id').count()
res = hunter.registry_keys().copy(deep=True)
res['count'] = res['id'].map(count['id'])
```

We have ascertained that `len(count) == len(res)` and that `count['id']` returns the total number of times `'registry_key_id'` is seen.

But all the values in `res['count']` are `NaN`.

Could you please assist in fixing that?

**Answer:**

Using a combination of Flab's and Yarnspinner's responses, I was able to cut down the time of counting and mapping the pandas from 1 hour to 12 seconds. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could give .map a try. After creating a dataframe containing the counts of each distinct id from your second dataframe, the reference_id in the first dataframe can be mapped there.

```
import pandas as pd
import string
import time

df1=pd.DataFrame(data= {"id": ["a","b","c","d"]*5,"value":range(20)}, index = range(20))
df2=pd.DataFrame(data= {"id": ["a","a","a","b","b","c"]*10,"whatever" : range(60)})

df1_1 = df1.copy()
df2_1 = df2.copy()

t0 = time.clock()
reference_df2 = df2.groupby("id").count()
for index,row in df1.iterrows():
    df1.loc[index] = (index,reference_df2["whatever"][1])
t1 = time.clock()
print "Simply assigning constant value from df2 with iterrows method: " + str(t1-t0)
# print df1

t0 = time.clock()
new_df2 = df2_1.groupby("id").count()
df1_1["id_count"] = df1_1["id"].map(new_df2["whatever"])
t1 = time.clock()
print "map method: " + str(t1-t0)
```

Map was quite abit faster.

```
Simply assigning constant value from df2 with iterrows method: 0.0124636374812
map method: 0.00155283320419
```

Comment: Everything seems to work up until we call map(). The 'count' returned is always NaN.

Comment: Dear Yarnspinner, we have included more information about our code and the error we're getting above. Could you please review and assist? Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

Starting from Yarnspinner answer, I agree you can divide the problem in two steps:
counting all the ids in df2 and than mapping this information in df1.

```
import pandas as pd
import string

df1=pd.DataFrame(data= {"id": ["a","b","c","d"]*5,"value":range(20)}, index =   range(20))
df2=pd.DataFrame(data= {"id": ["a","a","a","b","b","c"]*10,"whatever" : range(60)})


count_dict = df2.groupby('id').count().to_dict()['whatever']

# If a key in df1 is not in df2, then assign a 0 count
# This part can probably be optimised but is not the purpose of the question

unique_df1_id = df1['id'].unique().tolist()
for key in unique_df1_id:
    if key not in count_dict:
         count_dict[key] = 0

#Here you create a new column containing the desider output
df1.loc[:, 'id count'] = df1['id'].replace(count_dict)
```

Answer (score 0):

I think if you perform a left `merge` you can then count the dupes calling `value_counts` on 'id' column:

```
dt1.merge(dt2,left_on='id', right_on='registry_key_id', how='left')['id'].value_counts()
```

Comment: Unfortunately the size of the data frames are different. dt2 is significantly larger than dt1. Thus, a merge creates issues with the data.

Comment: So are you trying to match the lhs or the rhs?

Answer (score 0):

Would something like this work for you?

```
matches = dt2[dt2.registry_key_id.isin(dt1.id)]
count = len(matches)
```